# My function works in R console but not in R script

Tags: r

I tried to write some functions to calculate anova power and sample size using non-central parameter.

There're some very good functions in R but my functions were to learn and reproduce line of thought from a biostatistical book...

Despite de math involved, my "nc" and "fpower" functions just work well, and as expected:

```
nc <- function(diff,n,sd) {
  nonc <- (diff^2/2)*(n/sd^2)
  return(nonc)
}

fpower <- function(k,n,diff,sd,alpha=0.05) {
  nonc <- nc(diff,n,sd)
  dfn <- k - 1
  dfd <- k*(n-1)
  f1 <- qf(1-alpha,dfn,dfd)
  f2 <- pf(f1,dfn,dfd,nonc)
  return(1-f2)
}
```

However, my "fsample" just doesn´t work as expected. Return 2, the first n in the seq.

```
fsample <- function(k,diff,sd,alpha=0.05,power=0.9){
  for(n in 2:5000){
    if ( fpower(k,n,sd,alpha) >= power) break
  }
  return(n)
}
```

But, if I "hand" run this code in console it work as expected!! 
And return the right n value.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't pass the `diff` argument to `fpower`, so the arguments aren't in the order you think they are.  `fsample` should be:

```
fsample <- function(k,diff,sd,alpha=0.05,power=0.9){
  for(n in 2:5000){
    if ( fpower(k,n,diff,sd,alpha) >= power) break
  }
  return(n)
}
```

Note that this wouldn't have been a problem if you had named the arguments when you called `fpower` because you would have received an error about `diff` being missing and not having a default value:

```
# this will error
fsample <- function(k,diff,sd,alpha=0.05,power=0.9){
  for(n in 2:5000){
    if ( fpower(k=k,n=n,sd=sd,alpha=alpha) >= power) break
  }
  return(n)
}
```

Also, you might want to avoid giving data objects the same name as functions (e.g. `diff`, `sd`, and `power` are also functions), otherwise you may confuse yourself.

Comment: To clarify, assuming I read this right,  when executing these functions in the console,  `diff` is in the local environment so `fpower` can find it despite not being passed as an argument.